# How to add pistachios in a white chocolate mudcake

Tags: cake

I am planning to make a white chocolate mud cake with pistachios, white chocolate chips and dark chocolate chips. I know that there are several methods to prevent the chocolate chips sinking to the bottom. But do I have to take any precautions with the pistachios too? Should I dust them with flour or what things should I keep in mind to add pistachios to my cake? I would also like the pistachios to be a good size so that people can bite into them and taste them in the cake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dust all three inclusions (the chips and nuts) and then place half of the plain batter (that has no inclusions added) in the pan(s), add the inclusions to the remaining batter and mix lightly. Pour that batter evenly over the batter already in the pan(s) and bake. Don't cut the pistachios in more than half or they will be too small.

Comment: +1, thanks, that's very helpful. Just one more question, won't the pistachios sink to the bottom if they are only halved?

Comment: Its a balance; the smaller you chop or grind them, the less likely they are to sink, but the less textural contrast you will have.